# Change month name from other language to english in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

How to change month name from current locale (polish PL) to english language in Smarty?

I have this

```
 {$product->specificPrice.to|date_format:'%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'}
```

which gives me

```
 17 maj 2015 00:00:00
```

"maj" in polish language means May and i want to have this markup:

```
 17 May 2015 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set locale for time/date formats in your php code :

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, en_US.utf8);
```

If you want to output dates in English only in few places in your templates and keep your time/date locale Polish, you should write custom Smarty modifier and use it to output dates in your custom format.

Not best but simple way is to re-use smarty's date_format in your custom modifier, like following example shows (considering Smarty 3):

```
    class Smarty_Extended extends Smarty
    {
        private $_locale;

        public function __construct($defaultLocale)
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_locale = $defaultLocale;
            $this->loadPlugin('smarty_modifier_date_format');
            $this->registerPlugin('modifier', 'date_format_eng', [$this, 'smarty_modifier_date_format_eng']);
        }

        public function smarty_modifier_date_format_eng($string, $format = null, $default_date = '', $formatter = 'auto')
        {
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US.utf8');
            $date = smarty_modifier_date_format($string, $format, $default_date, $formatter);
            setlocale(LC_TIME, $this->_locale);
            return $date;
        }
    }
```

Now you can use date_format_eng in your template:

```
{$time|date_format_eng}
May 22, 2015
```